# Verb agreement with made up words

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

I've made up two words for my personal needs in a story. They are "**mostbody**" and "**fewbody**" used in a dialect in direct speech (see explanation here. [Introduce new English dialect](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/32460/introduce-new-english-dialect/32503#32503)). I would like to know if it's better to use plural or singular with these words?

- "I tells you that fewbody in our vil' **agree/agrees** with you."

I'm thinking of presenting "**fewbody**" as either a union or separate units. From what I know about "**everybody**", "**somebody**", or "**anybody**" - they all use only singular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreed, definitely use singular to parallel "everybody," "somebody," and "nobody."

Answer (score 0):

I don't think these words would work, nor do I think they are needed in English.  The usual way to express those ideas is simply to use the words *few* and *most* when referring to people.

For example:

*I am telling you that few in our village would agree with you.*

*There are few in our village who would agree with you.*

*I am telling you that most in our village would agree with you.*

*Most in our village would agree with you.*

Comment: I know the simple and common way, thank you. I'm intending to use a dialect and since I've changed "few" to "fewbody" I'm thinking it changes from plural to singular. However, I still think plural is possible.